How to raise an issue in one Jira service management project, but get a ticket created in another
Since I have many different service desks available on the portal, I want to create a main project that will contain a form with some conditions. Based on the user's choices, the user will be taken to the form fields relevant to the service desk they are trying to contact.
The aim is not to create tickets in the main project, but in the relevant project where the request is going to be handled.
Any idea how to handle the creation of the ticket in the desired  ServiceDesk project?
Project created with the relevant form.
So far, automation does not fully do what I am trying to achieve.
